# Why am I required to verify if a node is an instance of an Element?

Tags: java, xml, element, instanceof

I have made a simple XML file and I am trying to print the child nodes. I have managed to do it but it only works if I verify first that my *person* node is an instance of Element. I thought that elements are instance of nodes.

What I do in the code below is just take each item from a NodeList called *nameList* and turn the into an element so that I can print them to standard output. Why do I get an exception(java.lang.ClassCastException) if I don't check if *person* is an instance of Element?

Thanks in advance!

```
// Get the child nodes tag names from the root element
    System.out.println("These are the names in child nodes: ");
    NodeList nameList = element.getChildNodes();
    for(int i = 0; i < nameList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node person = nameList.item(i);
        if (person instanceof Element){
            Element name = (Element)person;
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since you can get an exception (presumably a ClassCastException) if you do the cast regardless, it follows that there are Nodes in your NodeList that are not Elements.  Because if they were Elements, you wouldn't get the exception. So the question is - what are they?   Why not add an 'else' clause to print out what they are  (say, the classname)?

Comment: What exception do you get when you don't check if `person` is an `Element` object? And which line would generate the exception you get?

Comment: Assuming that you are using the classes from the `org.w3c.dom` package: while it's true that every [`Element`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) is also a [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html), the inverse is not true: not every `Node` is an `Element` - it could be an [`Attr`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Attr.html) or a [`Comment`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Comment.html) or something else.

Comment: The Exception that is thrown is the java.lang.ClassCastException on the 7th line which is "Element name = (Element)person;"

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html), you're correct to say that `Element` extends `Node`, however it's not the only subclass of `node`

This inherently means that there could be another object extending Node in your `NodeList` which is not an Element, i.e [w3c.Notation](https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Notation.html).

Trying to cast any class to `Element` which is not an `Element` or a subclass of it will result you a ClassCastException.